# get particular strings from a text that separated by underscore

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the particular strings from the text below :

```
var str = "001AN_LAST_BRANCH_HYB_1hhhhh5_PBTsd_JENKIN.bin";
```

From this i have to get the following strings: "LAST", "BRANCH" and "JENKIN".
I used the code below to get "JENKIN";

```
var result = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("_") +1);
```

It will get the result "JENKIN.bin". I need only "JENKIN".
Also the input string `str` sometimes contains this ".bin" string.

Comment: You can try REGEX if you really want a special pattern

Comment: You cannot find JENKINS in '_JENKIN.bin'

Answer (score 2):

with substring() function you can extract text you need with defining start and end position. You have already found the start position with `str.lastIndexOf("_") +1` and adding end position with `str.indexOf(".")` to substring() function will give you the result you need.

```
var result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_") +1,str.indexOf("."));
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why this code is different from the code in the question, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: just added explanation per your request

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.split` to split a string into an array by a given separator:

```js
var str = '001AN_LAST_BRANCH_HYB_1hhhhh5_PBTsd_JENKIN.bin';

var parts = str.split('_'); 
// parts is ['001AN', 'LAST', 'BRANCH', 'HYB', '1hhhhh5', 'PBTsd', 'JENKIN.bin'];

document.body.innerText = parts[1] + ", " + parts[2] + " and " + parts[6].split('.')[0];
```

Comment: split with `.` for the last one I think

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how predictable the pattern is. How about:

```
var parts = str.replace(/\..+/, '').split('_');
```

And then parts[0] is 001AN, parts[1] is LAST, etc

Comment: Were you thinking str.split('.')[0].split('_')? Personally I don't like the idea of getting [0] of a function call like that, feels fragile, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: ...seems the comment I was replying to was removed... just justifying my use of a regex when not absolutely necessary

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/([A-Z])+(?=_B|_H|\.)/g` to match any number of uppercase letters followed by `"_B"` , `"_H"` or `"."`

```js
var str = "001AN_LAST_BRANCH_HYB_1hhhhh5_PBTsd_JENKIN.bin";
var res = str.match(/([A-Z])+(?=_B|_H|\.)/g);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to that, but this example would be helpful.

It will be better write what exactly you want.

```
str = '001AN_LAST_BRANCH_HYB_1hhhhh5_PBTsd_JENKIN.bin'

find = ['LAST', 'BRANCH', 'JENKINS']

found = []

for item in find:
    if item in str:
        found.append(item)

print found # ['LAST', 'BRANCH']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that way:

```
var re = /^[^_]*_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_.*_([^.]*)\..*$/;
var str = "001AN_LAST_BRANCH_HYB_1hhhhh5_PBTsd_JENKIN.bin";
var matches = re.exec(str);

console.log(matches[1]); // LAST
console.log(matches[2]); // BRANCH
console.log(matches[3]); // JENKIN
```

This way you can reuse your RegExp anytime you want, and it can be used in other languages too.